# jQuery Method to Parse Product Price/Cost Text from One Table Cell and Move to a New Adjacent Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, dom

I'm writing a bookmarklet for a jQuery-based product listing site, and I need to traverse the cells of a table that contain a product description with cost, and then separate that pricing info into its own cell.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="item" id="item-67601">Cricut Expression Cutting Machine - $119.00 <span class="db">*</span>   
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What I don't know how to do, at least not using jQuery (or any jQ plugin), is to parse out that price info, so that I can append it to a new adjacent table cell.

How might I go about doing this? Is there perhaps a simpler way to do it with native JS instead, or in addition? I'm curious what my options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just split on `- $` so you have an array with the name, and the price.

Something like

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var list = $(this).html().split(" - $");
    var name = list[0];
    var price = parseFloat(list[1]);
    alert(name + " with the price of $" + price);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPy7p/1/

With regular expression:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var matched = /(.*) - \$(.*) <sp.*/g.exec($(this).html())

    var name = matched[1];
    var price = matched[2];
    alert( name + "with the price " + price);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPy7p/3/

Comment: I guess I was originally approaching this problem with the thought of using some form of regex to resolve, but the split approach seems perfectly fine in this scenario. Thanks! :)

Comment: Updated my answer with regular expression. But I like the split more because then you don't have to have a `<span>`, haven't added it as optional to the regex.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the prettiest approach. Thanks for sharing the approach though, as I imagine I'm going to need to use regex at some point in the future. I take it the pattern.exec() syntax is native JS? Didn't see any jQuery documentation on it.

Comment: Yeah only the `$(this).html()` and the `$(".item").each()` are jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var val = $('.item').val(),
    price, des;
    price = parseInt(val, 10);
    des = val.replace(' - $'+price, '');
```

Comment: This seems slightly prone to error if, say, the product name has other numbers in it.